# Creating Additional Account Pages

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm attempting to customise the customer account page by adding an Orders page which can be linked from the main account page. This will link from the button below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvPAD.png

This button is on the `/account` page.

I've tried to make an additional template named `orders.liquid`, but when I go to `/account/orders`, I am redirected back to `/account` page

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjkem.png

How can I simply create an extra page with the URL `/orders` to link from the `account` page? I feel like I'm missing something quite big here (admittedly my knowledge isn't very good).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a new account template instead, since `order.liquid` is not a valid template.

Example: `account.orders.liquid`

And link to it using `/account?view=orders`

This way you will still be in the account page, but you will use a different template that you can modify the way you like.

Comment: Thank you, is that the only option? As obviously I would prefer a clean URL with `/account/orders` - but if Shopify is limited in this manner, then I can do it this way. Thanks.

Comment: @Matt I'm not aware of a different approach using only the provided tools from Shopify.